# Is it possible to create an app in VB6 that read/writes to a database hosted on a web server?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6

I was just wondering if it's possible to create an app that interacts with a database hosted on a web server... or is it only possible using VB.NET? Also if it is possible, is there any good documentation or tutorials I could reference?

Answer (score 0):

You may go through [this tutorial](http://www.vb6.us/guides/vb6-database-guide) for querying database from VB6.

Answer (score 0):

Tripping down the memory lane...

I think the [SOAP Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C943C0DD-CEEC-4088-9753-86F052EC8450) with a database wrapped through a soap webservice is your best chance to do this.

Other idea: client-side .NET Wrapper with COM Visible interface